# git reset HEAD~1 --soft made my staged files list full of files I haven't touched

Tags: git, git-reset

I accidentally committed two files to develop branch instead of my feature branch, but fortunately did **not** push them yet.

So I read how to undo that, so that I'll keep my changes and found the command

```
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
```

After running that my staged files list is now full of changes, file adds, file removes and whatnot. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you did the work on the wrong branch, the appropriate thing to do here is to find some way to move the work to the correct branch.  One option would be to cherry pick the incorrect commit from `develop` to `feature`:

```
# from feature
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of develop commit>
```

Then, remove the incorrect commit from `develop`:

```
# from develop
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Note that if you haven't even yet created the `feature` branch, then the solution gets a bit simpler:

```
# from develop
git branch feature
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This would create a new branch `feature` from the point in `develop` where you have made your commit, then it removes that commit from `develop`.